# How to tell if an exception wrapped in SomeException is an instance of a class?

Tags: haskell

I want to implement a class instance for a custom exception type and then use that class instance in the handler for the type. The code below shows what I'm trying to do; I'd like to find something that fits in the "???".

Here's the tricky part: I want to do this *without referring `MyException` in the handler*. For example, using `fromException` or `Data.Typeable.cast` wouldn't work. The reason is the handler will live in a one package and the exception type will live in another package. I want to be able to write additional packages that define their own exception types and `MyClass` instances, and I want the handler to be able to use these without knowing what the exception types are.

I know there are a lot of questions out there on "ways to tell if X is an instance of Y" but I haven't been able to get one to work in the presence of the `SomeException` wrapper. (For example: https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/AdvancedOverlap.)

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Main where

import Control.Exception

data MyException = MyException
  deriving Show
instance Exception MyException

class MyClass a where
  useMyClass :: a -> String

main :: IO ()
main = catch (throwIO MyException) $ \(SomeException e) -> do
  if ??? then (putStrLn ("Used custom exception class: " <> useMyClass e))
  else (putStrLn ("Showing exception: " <> show e))
```

Comment: By the way, if this is the only method in `MyClass`, then may I suggest `data MyException = MyException String` and just have everybody throw one of those?

Comment: The idea is to be able to catch existing exceptions in user code. We aren't able to change them, only write instances to improve how they're displayed. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: In that case, why did you accept my answer? It fails the exact same requirement, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I was accepting the "can't be done" statement :) (and the wrapper idea seems like the best option for anyone who has less stringent constraints than mine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't be done. However, you can make an open wrapper existential:

```
data SomeMyClass where SomeMyClass :: MyClass a => a -> SomeMyClass
```

Then you can require that all your users throw a `SomeMyClass` instead of their custom type, converting first by calling the `SomeMyClass` constructor if necessary.

```
catches (throwIO (SomeMyClass MyException))
    [ Handler (\(SomeMyClass e) -> putStrLn ("used custom exception: " <> useMyClass e))
    , Handler (\(SomeException e) -> putStrLn ("showing exception: " <> show e))
    ]
```